# Nodejs alternative template paths for template engine

Tags: node.js, express, pug, template-engine

Is there any solution to configure template engine use some alternative paths, as described below?

i.e.

- templates/{file}.jade
- ../template2/{file}.jade
- ../../template/{file}.jade

at first resolves 1st path, if file doesnot exist, runs for 2nd and so on..

i'm using express and jade.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, no. Jade uses the usual directory path structure not arbitrary file mapping, to map file to paths.

This is the natural and correct way. The directory structure would work for you too. If you want to implement a fallback, do it in node.js (for different files) or with express (for different requests). To be more precise do it in code, don't use include headers/lookup strategy to accomplish that.